# How to load NSURL that contains “#” with WebView?

Tags: cocoa, webview

I have a URL string which contains "#".For example,

```
NSString* urlStr = @"https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#/legacy/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/10-Configuring_Development_and_Distribution_Assets/identities_and_devices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH4-SW";
urlStr = [urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
[[self.webViewSample mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

After using encoding ,the "#" is replaced by "%23".If you don't use encoding, the NSURL will be nil.
My problem is that the webview load incorrect webpage which is different from Browser.How can I handle this url string so that I can load the correct webpage?

Comment: The ADC web pages are "optimized" for iOS as well. You can't really prevent the web view from redirecting to the mobile version instead of the desktop one, unless you somehow manage to change its user-agent string.

Comment: Why my desktop web browser can handle this correctly? does it change its user-agent?

Comment: (facepalm) no - it has a *different* user agent (you should read up on what that thing is).

Comment: After devices.html you are not giving"/".... :)https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#/legacy/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/10-Configuring_Development_and_Distribution_Assets/identities_and_devices.html/#/apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH4-SW

Comment: Can you clarify, is this iOS or OS X you're developing for?

Comment: @MikeAbdullah: It must be OS X, since UIWebViews don't respond to `mainFrame`.

Comment: @PeterHosey good point; I was thrown by the screenshot below, with nobody saying it was the wrong platform!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think from your question now, the root problem is that Apple's documentation uses some rather oddly formed URLs. They contain more than one `#` character, which isn't technically valid for a URL. The first is valid (and important); any others should be escaped.

Safari is able to handle this, I think because it does more than just display/use the raw URL string. The best solution I've found to date is to hand off to `WebView`'s pasteboard handling, like so:

```
- (NSURL *)URLFromString:(NSString *)string;
{
    static NSPasteboard *pboard;
    if (!pboard) pboard = [[NSPasteboard pasteboardWithUniqueName] retain];

    [pboard clearContents];
    [pboard writeObjects:@[string]];

    NSURL *result = [WebView URLFromPasteboard:pboard];
    return result;
}
```

More details at http://www.mikeabdullah.net/webkit-encode-unescaped-urls.html

Comment: Hey,Mike,I think this function is good.I have tried and it could replace the second # into %23.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> NSString* urlStr = @"https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#/legacy/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/10-Configuring_Development_and_Distribution_Assets/identities_and_devices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH4-SW";
> urlStr = [urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
> NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
> ```
>
> After using encoding ,the "#" is replaced by "%23".

Well, yeah. That's what you told it to do.

If you don't want that, then don't do that.

> If you don't use encoding, the NSURL will be nil.

That's because there are two #s, so your URL is invalid. It makes sense for even NSURL (which is VERY permissive about dodgy URLs) to reject it.

Take out the first, and only the first, #:

```
urlStr = [urlStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/#"
    withString:@""];
```

(That approach is a bit fragile; you could make it more robust by [finding the range of the first match](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString%3a) and then [only replacing within that range](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString%3awithString%3aoptions%3arange%3a).)

Now your URL is valid, so NSURL will have no problem with it.

Comment: so,how should I code the regular expression and make it common?

Comment: @gohamgx: I'm not sure what you mean by “common”, but the expression should be something like `/+#/+`, which you replace with `/`, and you should find the first match, then replace all matches within the range of the first match (which will replace that match only).

Comment: common means make the regular expression match most of situations

Comment: @gohamgx: The problem isn't that the plain-string search over the entire bogus-URL string doesn't match enough cases; it's that it matches too many: if the “URL”'s path ends with a slash, then that “/#” will get replaced, too. You only want to replace the first one. (Incidentally, now that I've looked up how to do it for my previous comment, I've realized that you could do the find-one-then-replace-only-that-one thing with the plain string just as well.)

Comment: @PeterHosey I'd argue `NSURL` isn't permissive about "dodgy" URLs at all. It strictly follows the RFCs with no room to manoeuvre around that

Comment: @MikeAbdullah: Unfortunately, the proposition that NSURL is permissive and the proposition that it strictly follows the RFCs aren't in conflict; for example, it accepts “Wonderland” as a URL. Technically, I can believe that it matches some pattern or other, but practically, I would not consider that a URL (at least not an absolute one).

Comment: @PeterHosey oh it's certainly not absolute, but it is valid on the way to building up an absolute URL from different pieces. I've always felt the top of the docs pretty useful on this: "The litmus test for conformance to RFC 1808 is as recommended in RFC 1808—specifically, whether the first two characters of resourceSpecifier are slashes (`//`)."

Answer (score 2):

try like this,

replace `#` with `/#` it'l work

```
UIWebView *web=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    NSString* urlStr = @"https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//#/legacy/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/10-Configuring_Development_and_Distribution_Assets/identities_and_devices.html/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH4-SW";
    urlStr = [urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    [web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
    [self.view addSubview:web];
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But my webview works well and it just loads not correct webpage.I replace "#" into "/#",the problem still exist.

Comment: I save this url as a bookmark,I click the bookmark and the browser open a new window loading it correctly.But I input this url to browser's url textfield and the browser jump to the page of navigation.I guess there is cache for the bookmark.

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem is that Apple's Documentation links are not valid URLs, so NSURL kind of does what its supposed to and refuses to make a URL out of it.

If you replace the second # with a %23, NSURL will be like "okaaaaaaaaay" and give you a NSURL object back, and your webview will open up to the correct page.

Comment: Deleting the first # (and one of the slashes on either side of it) accomplishes the same result, which is to make the URL valid.

Comment: Rewriting URLs (as removing the anchor point does) isn't necessarily the best thing to do. You don't know how it will be interpreted by the server receiving the request in the future.

Comment: yeah,so,there should be a function and make thing common

Comment: Not sure if there should be a built-in way to handle this; it is pretty rare. The *correct* thing here would be for Apple's Docs team to not use invalid URLs anywhere. But, that probably won't happen -- and if it does, it would break links all over the internet.

Comment: You mean I just handle this url for Apple ?

Comment: It's unlikely that any other URL will have multiple #'s in it without them already being percent encoded.